# c strcat with pointers

Tags: c, pointers, memory-management

I want to code this example function in C (please don't judge the purpose of that piece of code, it's only for learning the C). It should use dynamic allocation of memory to not consume more memory, than is neccesary.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

char ** LCS ( char * s1, char * s2 ) {
    int i, ii, myI;
    char ** commonSequence = (char**) malloc(1 * sizeof (char**));
    *commonSequence = NULL;

    int commonChars = 0;
    for (i = 0; i < (int)strlen(s1);i++) {
        for (ii = 0; ii < (int)strlen(s2); ii++) {
            if (s1[i] == s2[ii]) {
                commonChars++;
                if (commonChars > 1) {
                    commonSequence = (char**) realloc(commonSequence, (commonChars+1) * sizeof (char**));
                    strcat((char*)commonSequence, (const char *)s1[i]);
                }
                i++;
            }
        }
    }

    return commonSequence;
}

int main ( int argc, char * argv [] ) {
    char ** output = LCS((char*)"AATK", (char*)"AABC");

    printf("\n\nCommon: %s", *output);
    free(output);

    return 0;
}
```

The code above is causing the "Segmentation fault" error (perhaps something wrong with memory allocation or sth like that). When I run it in Valgrind, it outputs this:

```
==29381== ERROR SUMMARY: 1 errors from 1 contexts (suppressed: 3 from 3)
==29381==
==29381== 1 errors in context 1 of 1:
==29381== Invalid read of size 1
==29381==    at 0x4028A80: strcat (in /usr/lib/valgrind/vgpreload_memcheck-x86-l                                                                                          inux.so)
==29381==    by 0x80485BA: LCS(char*, char*) (main.cpp:19)
==29381==    by 0x8048626: main (main.cpp:31)
==29381==  Address 0x41 is not stack'd, malloc'd or (recently) free'd
```

Probably I'm not using the **strcat** function properly... But I actually don't know what to fix...

Comment: The large number of needless and/or inappropriate casts in your code should be ringing alarm bells. A cast should only ever be a last resort and should only be applied if you are 100% sure that you know what you are doing, since it silences otherwise helpful compiler errors/warnings.

Comment: @Paul: It's what happens when beginners try to compile C with a C++ compiler... :-(

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're casting `s1[i]`, which is a `char`, into a meaningless `const char *` pointer:

```
strcat((char*)commonSequence, (const char *)s1[i]);
```

You're also converting `commonSequence` from a `char **` to a `char *`, which won't work. You probably want something like:

```
strcat(*commonSequence, ((const char *)s1)[i]);
```

But there's really something wrong in the way you allocate memory for `commonSequence`. It looks like you're building a list of strings without allocating the strings themselves.

Comment: `((const char *)s1)[i]` still has type char not char*.  It does not need to be cast to const, that simply means that `strcat()` will not modify the data.  Just `&s1[i]` is needed for the second argument to be syntactically correct, although I am saying nothing about semantics - I agree with you, the original code is v. smelly.

Answer (score 2):

Your use of `malloc` is bogus, but since the numbers happen to work out right, the error likely won't be caught. This line:

```
char ** commonSequence = (char**) malloc(1 * sizeof (char**));
```

should read:

```
char ** commonSequence = malloc(1 * sizeof (char*));
```

or preferably:

```
char ** commonSequence = malloc(1 * sizeof *commonSequence);
```

The final form is the nicest because it does not require any changes if you change the type of `commonSequence`. As for the actual problem with the original line, you need to allocate based on the size of the object you will be pointing to, not the size of the pointer that points to it. In practice, since both are pointers they'll be the same size on modern real-world machines, but it's still a serious *conceptual* error that could bite you when you apply the incorrect pattern to non-pointer types. For instance this would result in memory corruption/undefined behavior:

```
struct foobar *foo = malloc(1 * sizeof (struct foobar *));
```

because it would only allocate 4 or 8 bytes instead of the size of the structure.

Comment: Without casting the commonSequence it will cause an error when compiling:

main.cpp:9: error: invalid conversion from ‘void*’ to ‘char**’

The malloc returns void*. btw. as it's written in the example here:
http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/clibrary/cstdlib/malloc/
It should be casted...

Comment: Actually "Without casting the returned value from malloc ... not commonSequence..."

Comment: Then you're writing C++, not C. They're different languages, and using `malloc` instead of `new` in C++ is a bad idea unless you're trying to interface with C code that needs to do the freeing.

Answer (score 0):

```
 strcat((char*)commonSequence, (const char *)s1[i]);
```

strcat needs a pointer, what you are doing there with `(const char *)s1[i]` is that you are accessing the character and then giving it in as a pointer. That is to say, instead of the address where the strcat should start, you are giving it the value of the character.

Answer (score 0):

You're allocating memory for a pointer-to-a-pointer to a string, but not for the string itself. The first argument to `strcat()` seems like it should be `*commonSequence`.

Answer (score 0):

You need to pass tha address of s1[i].  Simply casting it will not make it a valid address.  Equally casting a char** to a char* will not yield the result you expect.  You should dereference it to access the char* pointer stored in the char**

```
strcat( *commonSequence, &s1[i] );
```

That said, the rest of the code looks suspect.  What is it you are actually trying to acheve I wonder?  But you explicitly asked us not to question that!

Comment: Hi Clifford, the purpose of that function is to find the longest common substrings (but it's only the prototype).

Comment: @Radek:  I am prety certain that can be achieved without either strcat or dynamic memory.  If it is to find a string, whey does it return char** for example!?